# Select first space in line

Tags: regex, notepad++

I need regex to select the **first** space in line regardless of number of spaces or words on that line.

E.g.

```
aaa bbb ccc ddd fff ggg
```

I want only first space to be selected between `'aaa'` and `'bbb'`.

I created something like `^(\S+)\s` which selects `'aaa_'` but I only want the space to be selected and only first one in the line even if there is more spaces in it.

Thanks for feedback

Comment: Do you have multiple lines ? Also what language are you using ?

Comment: I copy something from a data base which has multiple lines. All comes as `First name Last name <email>` so I want to get rid of email column which is fine and then change spaces to tabs, the issue is that sometimes last names are double names which changes also that space to a tab. 

Once I get all to be
`First Name <tab> Last name <tab>` I can copy this to another system I use.

Comment: Funny and tiresome, after ~24h I get a reply ... The tiresome part is that what you just have said is totally different than what was asked in the question ... If you want to get ride of the last column, use `(?m)\s*\S+\s*$` and replace by nothing.

Comment: Ah and if you want to match the first space in each line you might use `(?m)^[^ ]+\K `, note the space after the `\K` escape sequence.

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
/\s/
```

If you don't use the global flag `g`, a regexp matches the first instance.

Comment: I did not mention that I would like to use Notepad ++ to search and replace via macros. I tried /\s/ and unfortunately that doesn't find any spaces :( Any ideas?

Comment: If you had a specific environment in mind, you should have mentioned it in the tags. Ask a generic question, get a generic answer.

Answer (score 1):

PHP example with regex

```
$str = 'aaa bbb ccc ddd fff ggg ';
preg_match_all('/\s/', $str, $matches);
print "-->".$matches[0][0]."<--";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can match the first space with a regex that just contains a space, e.g.:

```
PS Home:\> [regex]::Match('aaa bbb ccc ddd fff ggg', ' ')

Groups   : { }
Success  : True
Captures : { }
Index    : 3
Length   : 1
Value    :
```

Note that `\s` would match everything that is whitespace, including tabs, non-breaking space and a lot of other things, not just U+0020.

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = "aaa bbb ccc ddd fff ggg";
```

For **PHP preg_replace**: If you want to replace the first white-space only, **set limit**:

```
echo preg_replace('/\s/', "_", $str, 1);
```

*output*:

```
aaa_bbb ccc ddd fff ggg
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to change the first single white space character to a tab. Find and replace all should be fairly straightforward in Notepad++, just be sure to select the regular expressions.

You are correct in the way you identify the character:

```
^(\S+)\s
```

resulting in 'aaa_'

But when you go to replace it try this:

```
\1\t
```

resulting in 'aaa\t'

Answer (score 0):

Just exchange your capture group, instead of:

```
^(\S+)\s
```

type in the `Search what:`  box:

```
^\S+(\s)
```

The first space of a line will be captured in first group.